url works in browser but not from js fetch
Note that although this question references wikidata, it is really a javascript fetch question.  Also, this is not the wikidata api.  I'm just trying to load a simple page from a url.
I want to access wikidata using a QID.  My code generates a URL like
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q111943988

which works from the browser (try it).  But when I try to get it by calling fetch from the js script in my web page I get errors.  Here is my code ...
      const wdataResp = await fetch("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q111943988",
        {method: "GET",
         mode: 'no-cors',
         headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) ' +
                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' +
                         'Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
        });

It gives this response ...
wdataResp: Response
  body: null
  bodyUsed: false
  headers: <weird set of functions here>
  ok:false
  redirected:false
  status:0
  statusText:""
  type:"opaque"
  url:""

Note the ok:false.  I don't think this is a cors problem. I got cors errors from this code and the mode: 'no-cors'
fixed it.
Can someone give me ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

does this answer your question? Link

”I got cors errors from this code and the mode: 'no-cors' fixed it” — It didn’t. The problem is that the resource is CORS protected. You can’t “fix” that. The resource simply does not allow you to access it from a different domain.
